# How to use numpy.busday_offset to calculate the date n business days ago

Tags: python, numpy, date, datetime

I am trying to write a program that will calculate n-business days before the current date. For example, if I pass in 7/18/2021, and want to calculate 9 business days before, then the program should return 7/6/2021. I did some research and found that the numpy.busday_offset() can do this, but I am a bit unclear on how it works for calculating differences in dates. Could someone please clarify how to use this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need numpy for this? Why not do something like:

```
import datetime as dt

business_days = 9  # or whatever your input is
calendar_days = business_days + (business_days // 5) * 2 + 1 # Add 2 calendar days for each 5 business days

new_date = dt.datetime.today() - dt.timedelta(days=calendar_days)
```